# Scala/Spark: row of numbers to boolean mask

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I sought to obtain the mask of `boolean` values from an array of numbers whose type belongs to `Row`.
This mask is generated by the given threshold. The shortest way of getting this mask I've found is depicted on the figure below. Further, I'm going to apply this mask to the sequence of strings to keep only those which correspond to the `True` flags.
Is the way I did this mask optimal?
[image]

Comment: Please avoid pasting images of code and instead pate text code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two other methods to achieve this which at least avoid the intermediate conversion to string. Assuming `df` is the dataframe:

*Method 1*:

```
val numCols = 4
val threshold = 10000
val arr1 = Array.ofDim[Int](numCols)
df.map {
    r =>(0 until numCols).map(i => r.getInt(i))
}.collect()(0).copyToArray(arr1).map(_ > threshold)
```

*Method 2*:

```
val arr2 = df.collect()(0).getValuesMap[Int](df.columns)
  .values.toArray.map(_ > threshold)
```